# Syntactic dependency extraction using SpaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a relatively large corpus of sentences, such as:

*This phone rocks. It is everything I have ever dreamed of. You can go running with it, take it swimming, do what ever. It even holds battery very well. However, I am very displeased with the customer service by the company, so I won't be coming back there*

There is a lot of information in every sentence, why I am trying to use dependency parsing to break the sentences up, potentially being able to weigh each sub-sentence based on the relationship.

By doing

```
sentence = nlp(text) #refers to the quote above
displacy.serve(sentence, style = 'dep')
```

I get a nice visualization, such as parse tree :

[image]

However, I am having great difficulty traversing this parse tree and meaningfully splitting up the reviews.

What I have is as follows:

```
for chunk in sentence.noun_chunks:
    print(chunk.text)
```

Which outputs:

```
This phone rocks 

It

everything
I
You
it
it
what
It
battery
I
the customer service
the company
I

TL;DR:
```

How can I efficiently traverse the tree to subtract meaningful syntactic dependencies, such as:

```
'This phone rocks', 'it is everything I have ever dreamed of', However, I am very displeased with the customer service by the company, so I won't be coming back there
```

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Could you better clarify your idea so that we can help? Example: make a pair of "input" and "expected output".

Comment: constituency parser might fit your use case better